# Avoiding indexation by Lucene every time Java application is starting

Tags: java, indexing, lucene, hibernate-search

ISSUE: My issue is that indexation done by Lucene in my Java app is taking 50 minutes every time I am restarting the application.

WHAT I HAVE TRIED: Indices were saved in RAM so I have changed properties to "hibernate.directory.provider=filesystem". As a result the indices are saved in the HDD location, but unfortunately indexation is still being performed when application is restarting.

QUESTION: Does anyone know how to avoid overwriting indices by Lucene when restarting the app? My hibernate.search version is 4.4.3.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hibernate Search doesn't perform mass indexing on startup. If your application does, it's probably because of code *you* added to your application.

You should just tune that code to only perform mass indexing when you want.

Usually what I do is add a button to the administration console of my application, to perform mass indexing when I want. And I don't do it on startup.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Indeed indexer was initialized in a Bootstrap class and this was added by our team.